# SQL SELECT statement using multiple parameters and pulling out specific columns

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need help figuring out how to write a `SELECT` statement using multiple parameters chosen from multiple `listboxes`.  I then need to process through that row and return specific columns into `textboxes`.

What I am trying to do is fill the first `listbox` with a list of parent items and then using three more `listboxes`, I drill down to a specific part and then fill `textboxes` with the location of the final selection.

What I have so far is:

```
Private Sub GetPartDetails(ParentDesc As String, Description1 As String, Description2 As String, Description3 As String)

        SQL.AddParameter("@ParentDesc", ParentDesc)
        SQL.AddParameter("@Description1", Description1)
        SQL.AddParameter("@Description2", Description2)
        SQL.AddParameter("@Description3", Description3)

        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PartsListMenu WHERE ParentItem = @ParentDesc AND FirstDescriptor = Description1 AND SecondDescriptor = @Description2 AND ThirdDescriptor = Descriptor3;")


        For Each x As DataRow In SQL.DataBDataT.Rows

            txtCabinet.Text = x("Cabinet")
            txtDrawer.Text = x("Drawer")
            txtRow.Text = x("Row")
            txtSlot.Text = x("Slot")
            txtQuantity.Text = x("Quantity")
        Next

    End Sub
```

The following is where I call for the above code based on what has been selected in the four `listboxes`.

```
Private Sub lbThirdDescriptor_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbThirdDescriptor.SelectedIndexChanged
            txtCabinet.Clear()
            txtDrawer.Clear()
            txtRow.Clear()
            txtSlot.Clear()
            GetPartDetails(lbParentItem.Text, lbFirstDescriptor.Text, lbSecondDescriptor.Text, lbThirdDescriptor.Text)
End Sub
```

The `listboxes` are functioning properly and I have verified that each description parameter contains the proper `listbox`selections but when I select the last `listbox`, the `textboxes` do not populate with anything.  If I narrow down the `SELECT` statement to one parameter, it will fill the `textboxes` with the proper location information for the appropriate item from the chosen `listbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have typos in your actual code or just in the question here, but

```
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PartsListMenu WHERE ParentItem = @ParentDesc AND FirstDescriptor = Description1 AND SecondDescriptor = @Description2 AND ThirdDescriptor = Descriptor3;")
```

should be

```
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PartsListMenu WHERE ParentItem = @ParentDesc AND FirstDescriptor = @Description1 AND SecondDescriptor = @Description2 AND ThirdDescriptor = @Description3;")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  Changing that simple typo fix the problem.  I had been looking over this code for a few hours and I never caught that.  Always helps to get a second set of eyes on the code.

Comment: I spent hours this week trying to figure out why Tomcat couldn't find a specific file, until I finally realized I had given it the wrong name. Happens to us all!

Answer (score 0):

sorry to add this as an answer but I don't have enough points to comment. Why the loop if you are only selecting Top 1? Can you check `SQL.DataBDataT.Rows.Count` to see if you returned any rows? Not sure what technology this is but sometimes you have to Move First to get to the data.